# Changing background in CSS and putting a footer and a header on Chrome messes everything up. Why?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm currently working on a website that shows an image as a background everytime you hover on an article (so there's one background for each article).
I'm using this code:

```
.text1{
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: -30;
opacity:0;
transition:All 1s ease;
-webkit-transition:All 1s ease;
-moz-transition:All 1s ease;
-o-transition:All 1s ease;
}
.article_text1:hover .text1{
transition:All 1s ease;
-webkit-transition:All 1s ease;
-moz-transition:All 1s ease;
-o-transition:All 1s ease;
opacity: 1;}
```

.text1 is the class for the image and .article_text is the class for the article.
It works fine, but when combined with my footer and my header, for some reason it messes up, but only with Chrome. When you scroll down or up the page, they lose their fixed position.
Here's the code

```
header
{   
    z-index:10;
    font-size: 80px;
    letter-spacing:30px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:8%;
    top:0px;
}

footer
{
    z-index:10;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Does someone know how I can fix that?

Comment: can you provide pertinent layout HTML?

Comment: @juliep
would this be sufficient?
`<article class="article_text1">
  <img class="text1" src="IMAGES/BACKGROUNDS/text1.png"/>
  <div>
some text
  </div>
  </article>`

Comment: If you're having conflicts with styles, you should create a jsfiddle or similar. That's the only way we can help ;)

Comment: @juliep [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/Ty_u/2rtXL/1/)

Comment: This works for me on Chrome just fine. Mac/Chrome v30.0.1599.101. Or at least it works the same as FF

Comment: works for me too on Mac/Chrome v29.0.1547.57. I don't see the issue you are describing.

Comment: I see what you're talking about: When I scroll using the mouse wheel, the header and footer jump up and down a bit. Only in Chrome, and only when using the mouse wheel rather than the scroll bar. But is it that large a problem? When I'm done scrolling, they've ended up in their right positions again. (It's the canary yellow Chrome on Windows 7, 64bit here)

Comment: A bigger problem is that when the article is partially behind the header or the footer, the hovering effect doesn't occur when the cursor happens to be in front of the header. Or is that by design?

Comment: > juliep & JeremyCarlson well that's strange. I have this issue both on Windows 7 and 8.

@MrLister Yep that's what I'm talking about. Since the website will have many articles (so you'll obviously want to scroll a lot), I really don't want the visitor to have this issue to pop up everytime he hovers on an article and scrolls down a bit, that's gonna be annoying as hell.
For the hovering over the header and footer, I don't think it'll be too bothering, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: I think it's a bug, and I'm afraid there's not much you can do as a workaround. So, you'll have to decide if you want to put up with this behaviour, or to lose the transition.

Comment: that's too bad. Guess I'll put some browser conditions and put a "best viewed with Firefox" or something until someone finds another solution. Thanks for your help anyway!